# Can't I impute data in R using the prodNA function?

Tags: r, imputation

I am trying to impute some lost variables.

Some information of the data are:

- Number of Instances: 690
- Number of Attributes: 15 + class attribute
- Attribute Information:

  ```
    A1:   b, a.
    A2:   continuous.
    A3:   continuous.
    A4:   u, y, l, t.
    A5:   g, p, gg.
    A6:   c, d, cc, i, j, k, m, r, q, w, x, e, aa, ff.
    A7:   v, h, bb, j, n, z, dd, ff, o.
    A8:   continuous.
    A9:   t, f.
    A10:  t, f.
    A11:  continuous.
    A12:  t, f.
    A13:  g, p, s.
    A14:  continuous.
    A15:  continuous.
    A16: +,-         (class attribute)
  ```
- Missing Attribute Values:
        37 cases (5%) have one or more missing values.  The missing
        values from particular attributes are:

  ```
    A1:  12
    A2:  12
    A4:   6
    A5:   6
    A6:   9
    A7:   9
    A14: 13
  ```

```
#install.packages("missForest")
library(missForest)
datos2 <- prodNA(datos, noNA = 0.05)
datos2 <- missForest(datos, verbose = TRUE)
summary(datos2)
datos2$ximp
```

But the results come out as in data and not imputed.

Comment: please provide data

Comment: have a look at this blogpost and apply to your problem: https://www.r-bloggers.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/

Comment: What data is most needed? 690 instances, 16 variables. I need to use the missforest package.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with the `amelia` package. Like other imputation procedures, the results of the imputation need to be saved and then re-opened and re-structured prior to analysis. For example, I used this sequence to create imputed data:

```
library(amelia)
df<- ...a dataframe ...
dfImpute<-amelia(df,m=6,parallel="multicore",idvars="idvar")
write.amelia(obj=dfImpute,  impvar="impnum", file.stem = "outdata",separate=FALSE)
dfImpute<-read.csv("outdata.csv") #stacked 6 imputation files from write.amelia
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a quite simple mistake:

> But the results come out as in data and not imputed.

Look at you code:

```
#install.packages("missForest")
library(missForest)
datos2 <- prodNA(datos, noNA = 0.05)
datos2 <- missForest(datos, verbose = TRUE)
summary(datos2)
datos2$ximp
```

You provide `datos` instead of `datos2` (the data.frame with the missing data you created) to missForest. If you give the complete data.frame to `missForest`() then it just gives you the complete data back.

This would have fixed your problem:

```
datos2 <- missForest(datos2, verbose = TRUE)
```